# How to get top stories from Bing api

Tags: javascript, bing-api, feed

Okay, it seems that every question I post gets voted down, so I have went over the FAQ again, and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. If you are going to vote down the post, I would really appreciate some sort of comment or feedback letting me know what the stackoverflow community expects from a "good question" or how to properly ask I guess?.....

I'm having trouble figuring out how to get "Top news" or "Most popular" news from the Bing(azure) API.

I am able to search for "" and get all news results(most recent), but I can't figure out a way to pull the "Top news"(see top stories section here: http://www.bing.com/news?q=top+stories&FORM=Z9LH3 )

I've looked through the [documentation](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=272626&clcid=0x409) with no luck, and searched google. Does anyone know if Bing offers this functionality as part of their API?

Any suggestions?

Comment: Did my answer below solve your problem? Hope you've been able to get the Top Stories in your application, please let me know if you still need help (and maybe you could accept the answer if it did help)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to figure out a Bing API query is to use the Azure "[Service Explorer](https://datamarket.azure.com/dataset/explore/bing/search)" tool...

If you look at your initial URL you are simply looking at the news section with the query "top stories". In that case, I believe this is the query you're looking for:

https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Bing/Search/v1/Composite?Sources=%27news%27&Query=%27top%20stories%27&Options=%27EnableHighlighting%27

Also, the [documentation](https://datamarket.azure.com/dataset/5BA839F1-12CE-4CCE-BF57-A49D98D29A44) landing page for reference, describes the API parameters in some more detail.

Answer (score 0):

The selected answer is incorrect.

According to [Microsoft Support](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/6994e91a-317b-4575-aa6f-d8645b68e062/bing-search-operators-to-exclude-domain-from-results?forum=DataMarket),

> ...bing.com and Bing Search API do not provide feature or query results parity...

The selected answer will return results from the `News` API which contain or are relevant to the `Query` `top stories`. It will **not** return the same results as the [Bing.com News (Top Stories)](http://www.bing.com/news/search?q=Top%20Stories&FORM=NSBABR) page.

In the new API, the `Breaking News` query (an [empty query parameter in Bing.com API v2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd250884.aspx)) is not possible, as an empty query like `https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Bing/Search/v1/Composite?Sources=%27news%27&Query=%27%27&Options=%27EnableHighlighting%27`will return a small set of old (for me, October 2014) items.

I have a ticket in to Microsoft Support about this, and will update once I hear more.